# Best way to find out if a Pundit policy is used anywhere?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pundit

We're currently cleaning up our policies, removing deprecated ones.  Many of our models have policies with the same name, for example `view?` or `update?`.

Sometimes we just want to know if the user has permission to do a type of thing on a model.  These will be straightforward to search for in the code base:

```ruby
authorize Group, :view_all?
```

More often, we want to check whether the user can do something on a specific record:

```ruby
group = Group.find(@group_id)
authorize group, :view?
```

I'm looking for advice on the latter case.  For our longer model names, there are several different abbreviated forms we might use when retrieving an instance, not to mention any naming we do in context (e.g. `group_to_delete`), so the variable name isn't a given.

Comment: You can really approach this just like any other dead code removal. Pundit is after all just simple OOP. https://blog.kiprosh.com/dead-code-removal-approaches/